# Derivative of a function!

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I can't seem to figure this problem out! It asks to find the derivative of $\displaystyle g(x)=\frac{4e^{x/4}}{(x^2+x)(1-x)}$. Can you help me figure this out? Thanks~

Comment: Is this what you asked? I latexified question, is this correct?

Comment: yeah! thanks so much for fixing that for me, it's so readable now =D

Answer (score 5):

Step 1: Quotient rule.

Step 2: To find the derivative of $(x^2+x)(1-x)$, use product rule.

Step 3: To find the derivative of $4e^{x/4}$, use chain rule.

Comment: yup yup, you guys are good~

Comment: My version of Step 2: multiply out before differentiating (I prefer this to product rule)

Answer (score 2):

Recall the following rules:

- **Quotient Rule**: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right] = \dfrac{g(x)f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)}{(g(x))^2}$$
- **Product Rule**: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(x)g(x)] = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$$
- **Chain Rule**: $$\dfrac{d}{dx}[f(g(x))] = f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

Hint: Use chain, product and quotient rules to approach this problem.  You need to do a lot of differentiation!

Comment: Thanks for helping! It was a long problem,lol but I got the hang of it now! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the **product rule** for the denominator and then the **quotient rule**.
$$g(x)=\frac{4e^{x/4}}{(x^2+x)(1-x)}$$

Let $p(x)=(x^2+x)(1-x)$ where $f(x)=x^2+x$ and $h(x)=1-x$. 
$$\implies p'(x)=f(x)h'(x)+h(x)f'(x)\tag{product rule}$$

Then you'll have $$\frac{4e^{x/4}}{p'(x)}$$
To which you'll apply the **quotient rule**:
$$\implies g'(x)=\frac{p'(x)(4e^{x/4})'-(4e^{x/4})(p'(x))'}{[p'(x)]^2}$$

Also, to find $(4e^{x/4})'$, you'll need to use the **chain rule** where:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(4e^{x/4})=4e^{x/4}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)$$

Comment: awww yeah! i think I sorta got the hang of it, thanks so much for the help =]

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach when asked to find the derivative of a nasty product of functions is to use the logarithm, which can be thought of as replacing multiplication by addition. With this in mind given $g(x)=\frac{4e^{x/4}}{(x^2+x)(1-x)}$, we define 
$$
h(x)=\ln (g(x)) = \ln ( 4e^{x/4} ) -\ln (x^2 + x) - \ln (1-x)
$$
and compute 
$$
h'(x) = \frac{1}{g(x)} \cdot g'(x) = \frac{e^{x/4}}{4e^{x/4}} -\frac{2x+1}{x^2+x}+\frac{1}{1-x}
$$
which implies 
$$
g'(x)=g(x)\cdot h'(x)
$$
which we can get from simply multiplying the two things we have above. This approach allows us to abuse the linearity of the derivative with judicious use of properties of the natural logarithm. An added benefit is the simplicity involved in computing the derivative of the logarithm.